# Infinite loop on the edit text field

Tags: android, android-edittext

The code bellow runs infinite loop when number get greater into the edit text field.

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  String number = s.toString();
  boolean assign = true;
  if (!number.equals("")) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
    if (num > max) {
      if (assign) {
        s.replace(0,number.length(),number);
        assign = false;
      }
    } else {
      assign = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is max  value here?

Comment: I see no loop in this code.

Comment: @Bentaye the infinite loop condition is not caused by a loop clause in this case, it is linked to the way the afterTextChanged callback works.

Comment: @ahmadnaeem may I ask you to check my answer and accept it if you find it satisfactory ? Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `if (num > max)` and `if (assign)` always evaluate to true, so `s.replace(0,number.length(),number);` is always called.

As per the documentation for the `afterTextChanged` method:

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text
>   has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from
>   this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite
>   loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called
>   again recursively.

Modifying `s` directly is calling the `afterTextChanged` method again, which again modifies `s`, and so on.

Comment: well i use this flag textNoSuggestions in input type to avoid system focus mean by changing edittext by the code which cause loop. Well my problem is solved by this flag.